# How to find active QMainWindow instance?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Greetings all,

In my QT Application I have several QMainWindow instances.
I keep track of opended QWindow objects in a Application Context object;

At onepoint ,when a Menu item is clicked , I want to go through all this QWindows and check which Window is active and
execute some operations.

Please refer to following code snippet :

```
//Just a confirmation dialog
QMessageBox msgBox(this->getMainWindow());
msgBox.setText("This will discard existing project");
msgBox.setInformativeText("All Contour data and Volume data will be discarded");
msgBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
msgBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::Ok);
if(msgBox.exec()==QMessageBox::Cancel)
{
 return
}


//This is where I check the active window.

QList<MainWindow*> lst= applicationContext.getOpendedWindows();

for(i=0;i<lst.size();i++)
{
  MainWindow *win=lst.value(i);

   //Check if this is the active window
   if(win.isActive()){  // tried (win==QApplication::activeWindow()) also
      //DO SOMETHING with 'win' object
   }
  }
}
```

This check works fine when I dont show the confirmation dialog before the check.
That is, when I comment out the line 'msgBox.exe()' I can find an active window from the list.

Does the displaying of QMessageBox change the focused window?

Any tips on this?

Thanks in advance,

umanga

Comment: You do realize that you have posted the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447179/how-to-find-active-qmainwindow-instance and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447165/how-to-find-active-qmainwindow-instance

Comment: sorry for that,i deleted the duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple main windows, I think you also have multiple menus? If so, I would associate the slot reacting to the menu action with the mainwindow, either make it a slot of the mainwindow or a slot of an object that knows the corresponding main window.

You can also identify the active window before the messagebox, like Greg suggests, but I wouldn't consider that optimal either.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to your problem I can think of is running the check for the active window **before** you show the message box.

And yes, the `QMessageBox` becomes the active window once you call `msgBox.exec()`.